# How does background attachment fixed work?

Tags: html, css

I have some questions regarding background images when `background-attachment` is set `fixed`. These are:

1. Suppose I set a background image to a div of width 500px and height 500px with 1px solid red border. Now if I give `background-size: 100% 100%`. Why is the size of background image slightly greater than 500px? Why does the size of background image change when I change the size of viewport?
2. How do I assign a minimum height to the background image so that when veiwport's size changes the background image won't become smaller than a particular height?

Comment: Neither of these questions has anything to do with background-attachment. They're about background-size.

Comment: @BoltClock If I remove `backgrounder-attachment: fixed` then the background image doesn't take width and height relative to the viewport instead `background-size: 100%` would then set the width 100% of it;s container.

Comment: Also, these are two unrelated questions. Well, _different_ questions. They would be better off in separate questions.

Comment: @Chris Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/60bqdyu9/1/ I think I have found the answer. The size is set w.r.t the viewport's size.

Answer (score 1):

When background is `fixed` its relative to `body` element, that is why setting size of `100% 100%` results to greater width than `div` to which image is applied. It will be equal to body `width` not `div`.

If you want to set fixed `height` than you just need to set it in `px`, but in this case image will not save its ratio:

```css
div {
  background: url(//c6.staticflickr.com/8/7389/26907631325_f8b05bb68d_c.jpg) fixed left top/100% 433px no-repeat;
  width: 800px;
  height: 433px;
}

html {
  height: 10000px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: But why? Why would the background _size_ change if you change the background _attachment_?  This smacks of a bug.

Comment: @Mr Lister: See https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#background-positioning-area

Comment: @MrLister it just how it works, if it `fixed` then it's positioned relative to the `body`, like if element would have `position: fixed;`

Answer (score 0):

1. Your image is slightly greater than 500px because the border is considered as part of the image. Your background image is going to be 502x502 using this method.
2. On your background propriety you can assign a max-width and max-height so the image wont go smaller than a selected amount of pixels.

> Why does the size of background image change when I change the size of viewport?

This is because you set the image size in %. The % attribute is taking % size of his parent. In our case, the parent is the viewport ( equivalent to **vh** and **vw** ) and will change size if you change the viewport size.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think you can set a max width nor max height on a background image. Well not with a stylishness property AFAIK

Comment: The OP's problem is that the size of the background image, when measured in `%`, is relative to the size of the viewport (rather than the size of the element) if the background-attachment is `fixed`. See also my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/3b8kroar/1/).

Comment: @CraigWayne Sure you can. With a media query.

Comment: @Mr Lister: Well, if the constraints depend on the dimensions of the entire media, maybe...